# c# How to deserialize JSON to dictionary <uint32, string> but using also hex representation for keys

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to parse (deserialize) from a JSON file some `Dictionary<UInt32, string>`.
If `UInt32` is specified as decimal, works perfect. However, if I specify hex values, will fail :(
And I need to specify my numbers in both ways.

I am stuck in typeconverting, any hints?

Thanks in advance,

JSON for test

```
"TEST_DIC": {
    "0": "NONE",
    "40": "Value_40",
    "0x83": "Value_0x83",        <-- this will fail
}
```

Now in C#, my object is simple

using System.Text.Json;                   <-- using standard Microsoft JSON library
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

```
public class Cfg
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(HexConverter))]         <-- tried this converter
    public Dictionary<UInt32, string> TEST_DIC{ get; set; }
}
```

I tried to create a custom TypeConverter like this

```
public class HexConverter : JsonConverter<Dictionary<UInt32, string>>
{
    public override Dictionary<UInt32, string> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var value = reader.GetString();
        return null;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<uint, string> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The converter seems do nothing, are you looking for a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0)?

Comment: Given that the keys are always strings, you could also deserialize to Dictionary<string, string> and then convert to Dictionary<uint, string> in your application code. That's going to be much simpler than implementing a custom converter for dictionary, albeit may yield a bit worse results for things like swagger schema generation.

Comment: @Zdeněk Jelínek
I did that in my TypeConverter (returning new dic converted). Thanks. Pse add your reply to mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based of @Zdeněk Jelínek suggestion, here is my implementation.
Comments/improvements are welcome.

public class HexKeyDicConverter : JsonConverter<Dictionary<UInt32, string>>
{

```
public override Dictionary<UInt32, string> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    var dic = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(ref reader, options); // read as string/string dic first

    var newDict = new Dictionary<UInt32, string>();
    foreach (var kvp in dic)
    {
        UInt32 k;

        if (kvp.Key.StartsWith("0x"))
            k = UInt32.Parse(kvp.Key.Replace("0x", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        else
            k = UInt32.Parse(kvp.Key);

        newDict.Add(k, kvp.Value);

    }

    return newDict;
}

public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Dictionary<uint, string> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

Members should be decorated with:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(HexKeyDicConverter))]
    public Dictionary<UInt32, string> TEST_DIC { get; set; }
```